# Finding k-coloring (with k = 2/3) graph in linear time

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming, undirected-graph

**Question:**

Given a graph G = (V,E) a k-coloring of G is a labeling of the vertices with the colors c_1, c_2, ..., c_k such that for every edge (u,v) the color of u is different from the color of v.

A. Give a linear time algorithm that finds a 2-coloring for a tree.

B. Think about coloring a tree with two colors so that you have the maximum number of nodes colored c_1.  Prove that your algorithm from part (a), with a minor modification probably,  can be used to solve this problem.  Be precise.

C. Show an example of a tree, T, that can have at most j nodes colored c_1 in a 2-coloring but T can have j' > j nodes colored c_1 in a 3-coloring.  Try to find the smallest example of such a tree T.

D. Give a linear time dynamic programming algorithm that creates a 3-coloring for a tree such that the maximum number of nodes are colored c_1. Justify your answer.

**What I have:**

Parts A and B seem rather simple, but I am struggling on C and D

A. This seems simple, run DFS, but modify it so if it

1. encounters an uncolored node color it c1 and its children c2,
2. encounters a colored node color its children the opposite color
3. if it ever tries to "flip" the color of a child, then return that it is impossible to have k-coloring

This is just DFS, so will run at O(V+E)

**Edit: Since this a tree you can call BFS on a random node, alternating colors in the BFS**

B. Since this is a binary first choice (ie c1 or c2) and all choices follow from the first choice, we can simply calculate which is superior coloring the first node c1 or c2. We can do this by adding a counter to the above algorithm calculating the number of c1 nodes. Run the algorithm twice once starting with c1, then with c2, compare the number of c1 nodes between the two, and then pick the graph with more c1 nodes

C. Been fiddling with this for a while and can't find a single one, much less the smallest one possible

**Edit:  1-3, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, 4-6 described by Bing Wang works here**

D. No idea. I assume you are going to have to be using a modified DFS to have it run at linear, but am extremely unsure beyond that. I can come up with ways to brute force it, but nothing that runs at linear.

**Edit: Still confused about this**

Comment: What does your brute force algorithm look like? Decent chance you can just memoize it and have it run in linear time.

Comment: The rule on stack overflow is to ask [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735), so might you break your 4 questions down into separate posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c: 1-3, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5,4-6. This tree can have 3 nodes in each color in bi-color. But can have 4 nodes in the same color if you color node #3/#4 to two other colors - in a tri-color. You should be easily prove no smaller answer by going over all possibilities.

D: Just traverse the tree, e.g. DFS. Each node needs to keep c_1 count of all 3 colorings. WHen you deal with 1st node, that would be (1,0,0) - fairly easy count. Once you add the nodes into the visited, try all 3 colors, each color would be compatible with 2 colors of the connecting node, from which you pick the bigger one, etc, to construct the 3 values of current node.

```
E=[(1,3),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(4,6)]
V={v:set() for e in E for v in e}
[None if V[e[0]].add(e[1]) else V[e[1]].add(e[0]) for e in E]
serialized={}
def traverse(c):
    serialized[c]=V[c]
    [traverse(n) for n in V[c] if n not in serialized]
    
traverse(E[0][0])
visited=set()
for k,v in reversed(serialized.items()):
    filtered=v.intersection(visited)
    visited.add(k)
    m=[1+sum(max([V[child][1],V[child][2]]) for child in filtered)
        ,sum(max([V[child][0],V[child][2]]) for child in filtered)
        ,sum(max([V[child][0],V[child][1]]) for child in filtered)]
    V[k]=m
print(max(V[k]))
```

Comment: I would disagree call it O(V+E) which is a bit confusing, as in a tree, V=E+1

Comment: Slightly confused about the process you are describing in D.

what you describe seems to always prioritize c1 which isn't always optimal.

For example there are situations where the first node should not be c1 (1-2, 1-3 for example), but with the method you described it seems it will always be c1 as it will have [1, 0, 0] and therefore pick the biggest one of c1.

Unsure if I am missing something, as am new to dynamic programming, I am misunderstanding, or you made an error

Comment: @James added a code example. It can be further compacted but should work for any tree. This is O(N^2) and requires python3.7+

Comment: @BingWang didn't the original poster ask for linear time algorthim though

Comment: @MaxJones it is linear time. I miscounted the complexity

Answer (score 1):

A. Pick any vertex and color it c1. Run BFS from there. Everything at an odd distance gets c2 and at an even distance gets c1.

B. There are only two colorings, and they differ only in swapping c1 for c2. Run (A) and swap if you need to.

C. Imagine A and B are connected, and a has a number of other neighbors which are all leaves, as does B. With 2 colors you can get one more than the size of A or B a given color, but with three you can give two different colors to A & B, and color all the leaves the same color. The count of leaves depends on the j an j' inputs. If we're finding the smallest values of j and j' possible, then give each two leaves. Then you can have four c1 leaves with A c2 and B c3, as opposed to a max of 3 with only two colors.

Comment: Thanks for the help on A and C, but do you have any idea how to solve D?